# the redirect uri supplied in the request is not in the list of valid uri configured with this client application

Tags: android, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am trying to use andriod sdk,build is sucessfull however I am getting error(the redirect uri supplied in the request is not in the list of valid uri configured  with this client application) on login screen.I have registered my application(name docusignapp) with docusign and generated integration key and redirect url as http://localhost:3801 on docusign demo site.Same values are given in application.kindly help

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URL in your OAuth request must be **exactly** the same as one of the redirect URLs listed in the Integration Key's configuration.

You cannot add any query parameters, a fragment identifier, or anything else to the URL from the integration key's configuration.

If needed, you can use the `state` parameter to pass state information.